# ayuda con mi sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

como obtengo 5 valores más altos en una tabla?

Comment: Por favor leer [ask] y [mcve]. ¿Qué tabla? ¿Qué tipo de valores? ¿Qué has intentado?. Saludos

Comment: ¿Más altos basados en qué criterio? ¿De qué tabla? ¿Es una columna o conjunto de columnas? si no das más información acerca de tu pregunta, muy posiblemente acabe cerrada. Muéstranos que consulta estás haciendo, que te devuelve, y como quisieras que te devuelva la información, por ejemplo.

Comment: más que nada es en general, quiero obtener los valores más alto de un campo en un conjunto de registros

Comment: Intentaste ordenar los resultados `DESC`?

Comment: Parece pregunta de tarea o examen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obtener un número determinado de registros puedes valerte de la cláusula [`top`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) de la sentencia `select`.

Para que sean los N valores más altos, puedes valerte de la cláusula `order by` de la consulta, que se aplica antes de `top`.

Si quieres que sean los valores más altos, por ejemplo, ordena por el campo que tiene dicho valor de manera descendente, eso te dará primero el valor más alto, luego el que le sigue y así sucesivamente hasta el menor.  Como ya he dicho antes, `top` hará que obtengas solamente los primeros 5 valores.

En código, suponiendo que el valor que te interesa está en `MiCampo` y se encuentra almacenado en `MiTabla`, se vería algo como:

```
select top 5 MiCampo
  from MiTabla
 order by MiCampo desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

Select top 5.... From table where... Orderby

Comment: Saludos nuevamente. Te recomiendo que repases [answer]. Tu respuesta es más un comentario. Mi sugerencia es que la elimines y la publiques como comentario. Saludos

Comment: Tienes puntos de reputación que indican que conoces la funcionalidad del sitio. Sigue los links que te recomiendan para mejorar tu respuesta.